# AWS Ingress for socket application

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, deployment, socket.io, kubernetes-ingress

I have multiple microservices deployed on aws eks. one the microservices has external http access configured with my ingress file as below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cc-ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
            - path: /api
              pathType: Prefix
              backend:
                service:
                  name: microservice-name
                  port:
                    number: 3001
```

I want to deploy another microservice which interacts with socket protocol and in my local environment I call the service with postman like below:

```
ws://localhost:3001/some-route
```

so I need to deploy this microservice in aws and provide external access for it. I would be appreciated if anyone could help me.
Thanks for any comments or guides.

Comment: Web Socket uses TCP, so you have to allow TCP traffic on specific port in the relevant security group.

Comment: @AnkushJain I've allowed TCP traffic on that specific port but how should I write the ingress file for that? how can I expose it to send request to it?

Comment: @AnkushJain Could you help me with that?

Comment: I don't have experience with kubernetes, but you can try AWS Reachability Analyzer to troubleshoot which part is blocking the request. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/reachability/what-is-reachability-analyzer.html

Answer (score 0):

web socket works on top of https protocol, by adding an upgrade:connection header to the request. So, you don't have to rewrite the ingress specifically for web sockets. Just make sure you have https ports opened and the app is listening to it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what do you mean by adding an upgrade:connection header to the request?

Comment: when you use ws endpoint to connect to the server the request will go with this upgrade connection header to the server indicating that the client needs to talk in web socket protocol and the server respond with 101 status code (indicates a protocol switch). You can add this header to the request programatically depending on the language you use.